# Pattern-printing program - Unable to print the mirrored part in reverse order

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to create a pattern printing program.

I'm not able to print my pattern in reverse order. I know there's some logical error in the second `for` loop, but I can't identify it.

```
    public class test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 7;
        int temp1 = 1;
        int temp2 = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num / 2; i++) {
          for (int j = 1; j <= num - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          for (int k = 1; k <= temp1; k++) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(k - temp2));
          }
          temp1 += 2;
          temp2++;
          System.out.println();
        }
        temp1 = 1;
        temp2 = 1;
        for (int i = num - (num / 2); i >= 1; i--) {
          for (int j = 1; j <= num - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          for (int k = temp1; k >= 1; k--) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(k - temp2));
          }
          temp1 += 2;
          temp2++;
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
    }
```

Program output:

```
      0   
     101  
    21012 
   0      
    101   
     21012
      3210123
```

Expected output:

```
      0   
     101  
    21012 
   3210123
    21012
     101
      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the figure you need to print consist of three parts, you have to spit your solution into three separate methods. So it'll be easier to test them.

The *top* and *bottom* a very similar. The simplest approach you can take is to reuse the same code for *bottom part* with only one change: the index of the outer `for` is being initialed with a max value and will get decremented at each step of iteration (*you get it right, but you've also changed the inner `for` loop because your first block of loops is also responsible for printing the middle part*).

```
public static void print(int size) {
    printTopPart(size);
    if (size % 2 == 1) { // middle part will be printed if size is odd
        printMiddlePart(size);
    }
    printBottomPart(size);
}

public static void printTopPart(int size) {
    int height = size / 2;
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        // print the white space
        for (int i = 0; i < height - row; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // print the row of numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < row * 2 + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(row - i));
        }
        System.out.println(); // advance the output to the next row
    }
}

public static void printMiddlePart(int size) {
    // print the row of numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(Math.abs(size / 2 - i));
    }
    System.out.println(); // advance the output to the next row
}

public static void printBottomPart(int size) {
    int height = size / 2;
    for (int row = height - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        // print the white space
        for (int i = 0; i < height - row; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // print the row of numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < row * 2 + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(row - i));
        }
        System.out.println(); // advance the output to the next row
    }
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(7);
}
```

**Output**

```
   0
  101
 21012
3210123
 21012
  101
   0
```